# Input levels too high with Cubase 5 and Alesis IO2

Tags: cubase, levels

I am having an issue with recording my guitar in Cubase 5.  I am using Alesis IO2 as input and output.

The input appears to be unreasonably loud. I can see the levels in cubase go right to the max every time I pluck a string. I have messed with every knob on the Alesis hardware but the problem persists.

Any one have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the IO2 with the guitar input, with Mic/Line / Guitar switch set to guitar, I'd start by bringing down the gain knob then turning it up slowly. Also make sure that you aren't by some quirk of monitoring hearing the guitar coming straight through the interface AND having it come through Cubase at the same time?

If none of that works, you might need an inline pad between your guitar and the interface. You could do that with a special thing you plug your cable into, or even as simple as adjusting the volume control on your guitar.

Comment: It's very odd but when I set the gain all the way to 0 it gets slightly quieter but still the levels are maxed out. Also shouldn't there be no sound at all when at 0 gain? And I don't know how to tell if I'm hearing the guitar through the interface and through Cubase at the same time... that sounds like it could be the issue maybe.